# SDN+Ryu Controller + Mininet

Tags: networking, mininet, sdn, ryu

I made a topology on Mininet with 2 hosts and diffrent switches, I need to ping from host 1 to host 2 using different paths to compare performances.

So far I wrote a python script for Topology discovery.
But My issue is how to define a static route on ryu-controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can define that using the `addController` command in your py script file, defining the controller name, for example, `c0`, an Ip address to the controller, and the port number.
Here is a sample:

```py
net.addController('c0', controller=Remotecontroller, ip=`127.0.0.1`, port=6653)
```